# ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection

I've been trying to implement [this colab code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11ko0DBnI1QLxVoJQR8gt9b4JDcvbCrtU#scrollTo=PhAuO2-1ZBnv) but encountered this error in training part of the code.

(python version **Python 3.7.12** and tensorflow version **1.14**.)

```
!python3 /content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path={config_path + pipeline_file} \
    --model_dir={model_dir} \
    --alsologtostderr \
    --num_train_steps={num_steps} \
    --num_eval_steps={num_eval_steps}
```

I get this ImportError message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 25, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "/content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 30, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter as exporter_lib
  File "/content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 37, in <module>
    from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
  File "/content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/deepmac_meta_arch.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.models.keras_models import resnet_v1
  File "/content/gun_detection/models/research/object_detection/models/keras_models/resnet_v1.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.applications import resnet
ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet). : `tf.keras.applications.resnet` does not have `resnet`.

You can try:

```
from tf.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Doing this, gives me the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'

Comment: Although I have done this:-  `import tensorflow as tf` and then tried `from tf.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50`, still gives No module named 'tf'. I am new to this. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, how about `from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50`

Comment: No dear :-( it shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet'` at the same place. stuck in this error for weeks now.  Do you know any other alternate solution?

Comment: Hi I suggest that you try it on another platform (such as colab), to check is it a environment issue of you personal device.

Comment: Sir, I am running this program in google collab. Even this mentioned github code is from collab.

Comment: It's so weird, can you show you colab link?

Answer (score 0):

You can check here the [Tensorflow Library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/resnet50.py).

**Tensorflow 1.14** does not have `resnet`.
Right import is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet50
```

Comment: Sir, i tried it but still gave me an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.applications' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/__init__.py)`. Do you have any solution to this please ?

Comment: And if tensorflow 1.14 doesn't have `resnet` as you said, which tensorflow version should I use then?